# CSS @font-face rule making <h1> tag bold

Tags: css, font-face

I am getting confused in learning @font-face conceptually. Please see the below code. The text in <h1> tag is getting bold while the text of <div> (With CSS, websites can use) is normal.

So why <h1> tag is choosing sansation*bold.woff file instead of sansation*_light.woff ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

@font-face {
   font-family: myFirstFont;
   src: url(sansation_light.woff);
   font-weight: normal;

}

@font-face {
   font-family: myFirstFont;
   src: url(sansation_bold.woff);
   font-weight: bold;
   }


* {
   font-family: myFirstFont;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The @font-face Rule</h1>

<div>
With CSS, websites can use <b>fonts other than the pre-selected "web-safe" fonts</b>.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I reversed the sequence of bold and normal rules i.e, put bold rule first and then normal thinking it might be due to recency, but result is same:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: myFirstFont;
   src: url(sansation_bold.woff);
   font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
   font-family: myFirstFont;
   src: url(sansation_light.woff);
   font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: H1 by default has font-weight: bold. Using the browser dev tools is a great way to see what is happening!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I commented above, H1 tags have the following default styles:

```
h1 {
display: block;
font-size: 2em;
margin-block-start: 0.67em;
margin-block-end: 0.67em;
margin-inline-start: 0px;
margin-inline-end: 0px;
font-weight: bold; }
```

Making use of the browser developer tools will let you see where/what styles are being applied.

This is why you see many sites make use of a *Normalize CSS file* that helps create a baseline across all browsers, since all browsers assign default values to specific CSS properties, and each browser sets different ones.